Multiple time series, with horizontal scroll and toggle on/off
I am creating a Python plotly graph to display prices of multiple stocks. I'd like to be able to scroll horizontally and toggle each series on/off.
I found some examples here but there was no toggle:
https://plotly.com/python/time-series/
I found a toggle example (below) but it doesn't contain a horizontal scroll bar and it seems very complicated to add toggle behavior.
Would someone be able to help with a simpler example, say two stock series, with toggling and horizontal scroll? I can then extend it to 3/4/5/6 series.
Plotly: How to toggle traces with a button similar to clicking them in legend?
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime

NPERIODS = 200

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 12, size=(NPERIODS, 4)),
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                         periods=NPERIODS).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0] = 0
df = df.cumsum()

# set up multiple traces
traces = []
buttons = []
for col in df.columns:
    traces.append(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                            y=df[col],
                            visible=True,
                            name=col)
                )
    traces.append(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                y=df[col]+20,
                visible=True,
                name=col)
    )
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=col,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'visible':True},[i for i,x in enumerate(traces) if x.name == col]],
                        args2=[{'visible':'legendonly'},[i for i,x in enumerate(traces) if x.name == col]]
                        )
                )

allButton = [
    dict(
        method='restyle',
        label=col,
        visible=True,
        args=[{'visible':True}],
        args2=[{'visible':'legendonly'}]
    )
]

# create the layout 
layout = go.Layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type='buttons',
            direction='right',
            x=0.7,
            y=1.3,
            showactive=True,
            buttons=allButton + buttons
        )
    ],
    title=dict(text='Toggle Traces',x=0.5),
    showlegend=True
)

fig = go.Figure(data=traces,layout=layout)

# add dropdown menus to the figure
fig.show()


Is this that you're looking for?
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import List

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime


def plot_timeseries(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    columns: List[str] | str | None = None,
    title: str | None = None,
    add_buttons: bool = True,
    horizontal_slider: bool = True,
    errors: str = "ignore",
):
    """
    Plot a time series from a DataFrame.

    Generates a plotly figure for the given DataFrame, plotting specified
    numeric columns against the DataFrame's datetime index.
    Provides options for adding interactive buttons and a horizontal slider.

    .. important::

        This function assumes that the index of the dataframe contains
        datetime-like values. Otherwise, a `ValueError` is raised.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame
        The input DataFrame containing the data to plot.
        The index must be of datetime type.
    columns : List[str] | str | None
        Column name or list of column names to plot.
        If `None`, all numeric columns are plotted.
        If a single string is provided, only that column is plotted.
    title : str | None
        The title of the plot. If None, no title is displayed.
    add_buttons : bool, default=True
        If True, adds buttons to toggle the visibility of each trace.
        If the parameter `column` contains only one column name,
        or if the `df` dataframe contains a single column, then
        no buttons are added to the plot.
    horizontal_slider : bool, default=True
        If True, adds a horizontal slider to the x-axis.
    errors : str {'ignore', 'raise'}, default='ignore'
        Error handling strategy for non-numeric columns:

        - 'ignore': Non-numeric columns specified inside `columns` parameter are ignored.
        - 'raise': Raises an error for non-numeric columns.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If the DataFrame index is not of datetime type or if non-numeric columns
        are specified and `errors` is set to 'raise'.
    TypeError
        If `columns` is not a list, string, or None.

    Notes
    -----
    This function uses plotly to generate interactive plots. Ensure plotly is
    installed and properly configured in your environment.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> import pandas as pd

    Create a sample DataFrame:
    >>> dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=100, freq='D')
    >>> data = np.random.randn(100, 3)
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

    Plot the time series:
    >>> plot_timeseries(df)

    Plot specific columns with a title and buttons:
    >>> plot_timeseries(df, columns=['A', 'B'], title='Sample Plot', add_buttons=True)

    Plot single column. In this case, even if `add_buttons` is set to `True`,
    no buttons are displayed:
    >>> plot_timeseries(df, columns='A', title='Sample Plot of Column A', add_buttons=True)

    Plot only numeric columns given that dataframe also contains non-numeric columns:
    >>> plot_timeseries(df.astype({'B': str}))
    """
    if not pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(df.index):
        raise ValueError("Dataframe index is not a datetime index.")

    showlegend = True
    numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include="number").columns

    if columns is None:
        columns = numeric_columns
    elif isinstance(columns, str):
        columns = [columns]
    elif not isinstance(columns, list):
        raise TypeError("columns must be a list column names, a column name "
                        "or `None`, for plotting all numeric columns.")

    non_numeric_columns = set(columns) - set(numeric_columns)

    if len(non_numeric_columns) > 0:
        if errors == "ignore":
            columns = set(columns) & set(numeric_columns)
        else:
            non_numeric_columns_exception_detail = "\n".join(
                f"- '{column}':" f" {df[column].dtype}"
                for column in non_numeric_columns
            )
            raise ValueError("Some of the columns provided are have values "
                             "that are not numeric:\n"
                             f"{non_numeric_columns_exception_detail}")

    if len(columns) == 0:
        print("Nothing to plot")
        return

    if len(columns) == 1:
        add_buttons = False
        showlegend = False

    # set up multiple traces
    traces = []

    for col in columns:
        traces.append(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[col], visible=True, name=col))

    layout_dict = {"showlegend": showlegend}

    if isinstance(title, str):
        layout_dict["title"] = {"text": title}

    if add_buttons:
        buttons = [
            {
                "method": "restyle",
                "label": "All",
                "visible": True,
                "args": [{"visible": True}],
                "args2": [{"visible": "legendonly"}],
            },
            *[
                dict(
                    method="restyle",
                    label=col,
                    visible=True,
                    args=[{"visible": [x.name == col for x in traces]}],
                    args2=[
                        {"visible": "legendonly"},
                        [i for i, x in enumerate(traces) if x.name == col],
                    ],
                )
                for col in columns
            ]
        ]
        layout_dict["updatemenus"] = [
            {
                "type": "buttons",
                "direction": "right",
                "x": 1,
                "y": 1.6,
                "showactive": True,
                "buttons": buttons,
            }
        ]

    layout = go.Layout(**layout_dict)

    fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
    fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=horizontal_slider)
    fig.show()

The above code lets you plot multiple columns from a dataframe that contains datetime-like index and a bunch of numeric columns. For example:
NPERIODS = 200

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 12, size=(NPERIODS, 4)),
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                         periods=NPERIODS).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0] = 0
df = df.cumsum()
plot_timeseries(df)

Returns the following plot:

